# text view going below screen how to fix this

Tags: android

i am trying to add a big text  using text-view but its going below the screen please tell me how to make it fix the screen 
is there a better way to display text than text view
i cant add my fonts it shows box so i used a random text for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.07" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="The organization and coordination of the     
  Management is often included as a factor of production along with         machines, materials, and money. According to the management guru Peter Drucker (1909-2005), the basic task of management includes both marketing and innovation. Practice of modern management originates from the 16th century study of low-efficiency and failures of certain enterprises, conducted by the English statesman Sir Thomas More (1478-1535). Management consists of the interlocking functions of creating corporate policy and organizing, planning, controlling, and directing an organization's resources in order to achieve the objectives of that policy.

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
        android:text="Next" />



  </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your code not enough to give a answer. So please it would be helpful if you post your snap shot too. Because this is not a major issue.

Comment: Check this corrected code: https://justpaste.it/k6gz

Comment: ok will use this code and try

Comment: ScrollView can host only one direct child
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log is the error i got :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ScrollView instead of a LinearLayout as your wrapper view.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<!--everything else-->

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thank you . now i can scroll down my text . but my buttons get out of position how to fix them ?

Comment: Define "out of position" please. If it's what I'm guessing, add `android:layout_below="@id/textView1"` to your button.

Comment: could not add image :(  my buttons went  up to  top of the screen but i planned them to be at the bottom

Comment: all i want is a  text view that fills with lot of texts ... since i know scroll view will do the trick its done .. i want 2 buttons at the bottom of the screen after the text view which used to navigate to next page and one to exit

Comment: plus i cant aline the text too its going out of control

Comment: My general advice would be to switch your relative layout to a linearlayout. Relativelayouts are a bit harder to control and populate correctly while linearlayouts add one element after another in a sequential fashion. It's easier to get the hang of if you're just starting out.